# Скрыть родительскую страницу в url

Tags: .htaccess

Есть страницы вида `site.ru/simple-page/XXXX` и 
`site.ru/simple-page/XXXX/XXXX`, где `XXXX`- это произвольные страницы.

Нужно получить `site.ru/XXXX` и `site.ru/XXXX/XXXX`, т.е просто удалить `simple-page` из url.
Но у меня ничего не получилось.

Comment: что именно у Вас не получилось? покажите, что Вы пробовали сделать сами(ваш код).

Comment: RewriteRule ^simple-page/(.+)$ http://www.site.com/$1 [R=301,L]
это только один из многих вариантов. много примеров пытался адаптировать под себя.